# Search for file using string plus regex - Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, vbscript, hta

I've been writing a script that lets the user press a button three times, once the three times are up the button is to be greyed out and unclickable. I've made it so that the button cannot be clicked (using VBScript) but I want to use Javascript to also grey out at that point.

What I want to do is have javascript search for a file on the users local drive         `"C:/sys/"` and if that file exists then grey out the button.

The issue that I having is that the only part of the file name that I know will be correct is the last two characters "-3" the beginning of the file name could be any amount of alphanumeric characters. I thought I could use a regex to find the file but I have no idea how to get the script to search for the file using the directory path + the regex. Example for the code:

```
function checkfile()
  {
    var fileLocation = "C:/sys/"
    var regex = new RegExp('\w+\-3');
    if(fso.FileExists(fileLocation + regex)) {
      alert("File found successfully");
    } else {
      alert("File not found.");
    }
  }
  window.onload = checkfile;
```

I thought that might work but thinking about it makes me wonder if that script is actually searching for a file called "C:/sys/\w+-3" literally rather than using the regex.

Bare in mind that this is part of a much larger script so "fso" is already defined using `Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")` in VBScript.

The whole code can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/S49A80E7)

```
<script language="VBScript"> 
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")    
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    System = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\"
    DisableTaskMgr
    dim currentDir : currentDir = objShell.CurrentDirectory 'Finds the scripts current directory'
    'TO DO: Check whether UserName method below can be used over network'
    UserName = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERNAME%") 'Grabs the username of the current user'
    pathToConfig = currentDir & "/config.ini"
    pathToKeyFile = "C:/sys/"


    'Gets the current version number from config file'
    If fso.FileExists(pathToConfig) Then 'Makes sure that the config file exists'
      Set ConfigFile = fso.GetFile(pathToConfig) 'Config file contains only the version number'
      If ConfigFile.Size > 0 Then 'This makes sure that there is a version number set inside the config file'
        Set versionFile = fso.OpenTextFile(pathToConfig, 1)
        Version = versionFile.ReadAll
      Else
        EnableTaskMgr
        window.close 'If config file cannot be reached then the script will end prematurely and will be shown next time the user logs in once the config file can be reached.'
      End If
    Else
      window.close
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    versionFile.close

    'Searches C:/sys/ for keyfile'
    If fso.FileExists(pathToKeyFile & Version) Then
      EnableTaskMgr
      window.close
    Else
    End If

    sub Postpone
    ChkOne = pathToKeyFile & Version & "-1"
    ChkTwo = pathToKeyFile & Version & "-2"
    ChkThree = pathToKeyFile & Version & "-3"

      If fso.FileExists(ChkThree) Then
        'Placeholder code'
        MsgBox "Maximum number of Postpone attempts used. You must now choose to either Accept or Decline the Policy."
      ElseIf fso.FileExists(ChkTwo) Then
        'Delete file ChkTwo - Create file ChkThree'
        fso.DeleteFile(ChkTwo)
        Set objFile = fso.CreateTextFile(ChkThree)
        window.close
      ElseIf fso.FileExists(ChkOne) Then
        'Delete file ChkOne - Create file ChkTwo'
        fso.DeleteFile(ChkOne)
        Set objFile = fso.CreateTextFile(ChkTwo)
        window.close
      Else
        'Create file ChkOne'
        Set objFile = fso.CreateTextFile(ChkOne)
        window.close
      End If
    end sub

    sub DisableTaskMgr
      objShell.RegWrite System, "REG_SZ"
      objShell.RegWrite System & "/DisableTaskMgr", 1, "REG_DWORD"
    end sub

    sub EnableTaskMgr
      objShell.RegWrite System, "REG_SZ"
      objShell.RegWrite System & "/DisableTaskMgr", 0, "REG_DWORD"
    end sub

    sub Logon 'Method only runs when user clicks "I Accept"'
      On Error Resume Next
      Call EnableTaskMgr
      If Not (fso.FileExists(currentDir & "/store/" & LCase(UserName) & ".csv")) Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Set objFile = fso.CreateTextFile(currentDir & "/store/" & LCase(UserName) & ".csv", True)
        objFile.close
      Else      
      End If
      Set objCSVFile = fso.OpenTextFile(currentDir & "/store/" & UserName & ".csv", 2, True)
      objCSVFile.Write(UserName & "," & Now & "," & Version)
      objCSVFile.Close 
      On Error Resume Next
      fso.CreateTextFile("C:/sys/" & Version)
      window.close   
    end sub

    sub Logoff 'Method only runs when user clicks "I Decline"'
      objShell.Run "shutdown /l"
    end sub
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function checkfile()
  {
    var fileLocation = "C:/sys/"
    var regex = new RegExp('\w+\-3');
    if(fso.FileExists(fileLocation + regex)) {
      alert("File found successfully");
    } else {
      alert("File not found.");
    }
  }
  window.onload = checkfile;
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, `"C:/sys/\w+\-3"` will be searched. Instead you could read all the files from a path, and then filter the collection with a RegExp.